# Splitting an Unsigned Long in C++

Tags: c++, string, xcode, split, unsigned

I have an hexadecimal number 0x5ED3710573047010 which I want to split in two parts equally.Should I convert it into a string and split the string then convert the two strings back to an Int and store it in two separate variables? or there is some easy and quick way to do it using some kind of bit shifting or maths?

Comment: *Should I convert it into a string...*  Is it a string to begin with?  If not, what is it to start with?

Comment: @Eljay its a unsigned long data type to begin with

Comment: This is pleading for a "when done, I want two unsigned int values that look like this: " based on your example.

Comment: @ @WhozCraig sad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use masking and bit operations.

```
unsigned int first_half = (my_long & 0xffffffff00000000) >> 32;
unsigned int second_half = my_long & 0x00000000ffffffff;
```